# Reaching Absolute Zero by Adiabatic Expansion

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, adiabatic

We know that an adiabatic expansion of a P-V system leads to reduction of temperature. Can this method be employed to continually reduce the temperature until we have exhausted the systems complete internal energy and thus attaining absolute zero temperature? Where is the caveat here?

Comment: refer: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Thermodynamics_and_Chemical_Equilibrium_(Ellgen)/11%3A_The_Third_Law_Absolute_Entropy_and_the_Gibbs_Free_Energy_of_Formation/11.13%3A_Absolute_Zero_is_Unattainable

Answer (score 2):

One simple problem in the ideal case is that during adiabatic expansion, the temperature and volume are linked:

$$TV^{\gamma - 1} = k$$

As the volume increases, the temperature drops.  But you want to go all the way to  $T=0$.  I think you can see that you will have difficulty getting $V$ to be sufficiently large to make that happen.

For other problems, you have to have internal pressure so that it can do work on the environment.  If you have sufficient pressure and low temperatures, your substance is going to condense or solidify, making it really hard to extract energy via expansion.

When the gas has very low energy, extraction by expansion is inefficient.  The volume has to become large without bound, and the useful expansion rate decreases.

Comment: It is understandable that the volume needs to reach infinity in order to reach absolute zero for an ideal gas. But the gas liquifies and then solidifies at  when the temperature becomes sufficiently low as you said. In the non-gas stage is the argument of the volume needing to go to infinity still valid? ( can you give the necessary equations) And why is extraction of energy inefficient at low temperatures?

Comment: Expansion is not valid for extracting work from solids and liquids because they do not exert pressure (do work) as the volume is increased.  Extraction becomes inefficient because the system must be in equilibrium. If you move the piston faster than the molecules, you get https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion instead, and no work is done.  As the molecules slow down/spread apart, you have to wait longer to get anything done.

Comment: Reversible processes in principle take infinite time..but the extraction of heat via adiabatic expansion can also be done for irreversible (fast) process which need not be in equilibrium. If I am right in about this info then why would the extraction be inefficient?

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine this question from a more conceptual standpoint.

The temperature of an ideal gas is a statistical property of that gas, defined as the average kinetic energy of a huge number of atoms (or molecules) that are traveling inside their container in 3D space.  These atoms are elastically bouncing off the walls of their container and they are elastically bouncing off each other such that the momentum and kinetic energy of each collision is conserved.  This means that there are VERY many "glancing" collisions, where the colliding atoms are "bouncing" away in various directions, at various speeds.

For the case of adiabatic expansion, the volume of the container is increased while no heat is transferred from or to the environment, and the atoms have more room to move around.  Due to this, there are less collisions among atoms in a given amount of time, and the measured temperature of the expanded gas drops as a result.  Given this effect, it would seem that this process could be repeated several times to arrive at a temperature of absolute zero.

This leads to the question of what absolute zero temperature represents.  Because of how temperature is defined, absolute zero temperature corresponds to zero kinetic energy of ALL of the atoms in a container.  This means that each and every atom in the container is stationary with respect to the walls of the container and with respect to every other atom in that container.  Given that requirement, the question becomes "what is the probability that a container can hold a large number of atoms, such that increasing the volume of that container can cause all of the atoms to become absolutely and simultaneously stationary while conserving momentum and kinetic energy whenever any collision occurs?".  If the container holds only one atom, the probability is fairly high.  If the container holds 10 or 20 atoms, the probability becomes quite a bit lower.  Unfortunately, the definition of temperature is statistical, so a large number of atoms is required in order to establish a temperature for the system (e.g., several thousand atoms minimum).  Under the conditions of only several thousand atoms, it is seen that the probability of having all atoms absolutely motionless at the same time via adiabatic expansion alone, is more or less zero.